# HTTP Get Request with Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

Im trying to do Http Get request with alamofire but somehow Im getting this error.Also I use AlamofireObjectMapper for mapping . But where do I make mistake ?  [image]

this is my code:

```
class Networking  {

    static var sessionManager : SessionManager = {

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default

        config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120
        config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 120

        let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: config)

        return manager

    }()


    static var header : [String : String] {

        get  {
            return [

                "Content-Type" : "application/json"

            ]

        }

    }

    static func getMainIndex() -> DataRequest {

        var urlComponents = URLComponents()

        urlComponents.scheme = "https"
        urlComponents.host = "unitedshopapp.tsoft.club/mobile-app"
        urlComponents.path = URLPath.mainIndex

        print("\n\n\n\(urlComponents.string!) Sending Request .......\n\n\n")

        return Networking.sessionManager.request(urlComponents.string!, method: .get ,encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers: header)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`urlComponents.host = "unitedshopapp.tsoft.club/mobile-app"` looks wrong - "mobile-app" isn't part of the host name, but rather part of the path, and should be moved to the line below:

```
urlComponents.scheme = "https"
urlComponents.host = "unitedshopapp.tsoft.club"
urlComponents.path = "mobile-app/" + URLPath.mainIndex
```